# How to start socket.io server on specific public ip?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to load my socket server on my public IP because right now I can only load it on LAN `localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080`. I want to connect with my own IP `77.90.100.55:8080`.

I don't know why but I can't use

```
io.connect('http://77.90.100.55:8888');
```

to connect, only this one works:

```
io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
```

When I try to connect with `77.90.100.55` I get this error on client side:

> polling-xhr.js:264 GET http://77.90.100.55:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LpBv_sK net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

#### Server

```
var http = require("http").createServer(), io = require("socket.io").listen(http);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

http.listen(port);


//================================  Connection stuff ================================//
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket)
{
    socket.on('player connected', function(data)
    {   

    });

});

console.log('Server listening on port %s', http.address().port);
```

#### Update

I can use all ports and public IP and I can reach my IP through the command line:

```
Pinging 77.90.100.55 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 77.90.100.55: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 77.90.100.55: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 77.90.100.55: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 77.90.100.55: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 77.90.100.55:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

I run the node server with `start.bat`:

```
node C:\xamppp\htdocs\pure2d\server\server.js 2>error_log.log
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with node.js. Make sure that your network is configured to portfoward 8888 from your machine's local address to the public address. By default, consumer routers block all incoming traffic.

Comment: I don't have router and my internet provider let me use all ports and public ip, I can host any game and others can connect, all connection from client side good because when I use localhost everything works fine

Comment: Okay, try changing `io = require('socket.io').listen(http)` to `io = require('socket.io')(http)`. Also make sure that your `http` server has a handler. See [this documentation](https://socket.io/docs/#using-with-node-http-server) for reference.

Comment: changing code to `io = require('socket.io')(http)` didn't work

Comment: maybe I can't use public ip because of using with Node http server and I should use express server or it doesn't matter

Comment: express offers no more compatibility than http. I'm not entirely sure what the issue is right now, but express is only a wrapper API with a library full of convenience functions, but fundamentally does the same thing as the native http server.

Comment: Oh, does it correctly read `process.env.port`? Typically the port is passed through `process.env.PORT`, so make sure it isn't running on port 3000.

Comment: hmm i tried remove 3000 and leave `var port = process.env.port;` but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What port does it bind to when you do that?

Comment: nothing server close automaticly

Comment: Then you're not providing the environment variable properly. How are you running the server? What's the command?

Comment: i have error log https://pastebin.com/a4xvSTJr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147389/discussion-between-patrick-roberts-and-tioww).

Comment: i run it with .bat `node server.js 2>error_log.log`

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**
I used website http://whatismyipaddress.com/ to get my ip but I forgot that I have wifi router that change my ip and I can check that ip only from computer **network and sharing panel** because website can't show it.

Comment: You have a dynamic IP address? Ugh, I wish you had mentioned that sooner.

Comment: anyway thanks for help because you helped me with some code lines